# Dolby Audio API returning -1 when using initialize()

Tags: dolby-audio-api

I can't get the API to connect to the device via API. initialize() is returning -1

Here is the error log I am getting:

```
I/DSJavaPlugin( 3346): DSJavaPlugin v1.0
I/DSJavaPlugin( 3346): dolby.ds.state is: on
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Failed resolving Lcom/dolby/dap/DsClient13Wrapper; interface 32     'Landroid/dolby/IDsClientEvents;'
D/dalvikvm( 3346): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.test.app/lib/libDSPlugin.so 0x415d3630
D/dalvikvm( 3346): Shared lib '/data/data/com.test.app/lib/libDSPlugin.so' already loaded in same CL 0x415d3630
W/dalvikvm( 3346): Link of class 'Lcom/dolby/dap/DsClient13Wrapper;' failed
E/dalvikvm( 3346): Could not find class 'com.dolby.dap.DsClient13Wrapper', referenced from method com.dolby.dap.DsClientFactory.createDsClient
W/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 123 (Lcom/dolby/dap/DsClient13Wrapper;) in Lcom/dolby/dap/DsClientFactory;
D/dalvikvm( 3346): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0009
I/dalvikvm( 3346): Failed resolving Lcom/dolby/dap/DsClient13Wrapper; interface 32 'Landroid/dolby/IDsClientEvents;'
W/dalvikvm( 3346): Link of class 'Lcom/dolby/dap/DsClient13Wrapper;' failed
```

D/dalvikvm( 3346): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x01b3 at 0x0b in Lcom/dolby/dap/DsClientFactory;.createDsClient
    I/DSPluginJNI( 3346): [callMethodWithBoolReturn] java_rtn = 00000001
    I/DSPluginJNI( 3346): [callMethodWithIntReturn] java_rtn = ffffffff
    I/DsClientFactory( 3346): DsClient is: android.media.dolby.DolbySurroundClient
    I/DsClient07Wrapper( 3346): onClientConnected v=DS version 0.7.0.0
    I/DSJavaPlugin( 3346): Dolby client connected…

Answer (score 0):

Because the initialize() is happening before the Dolby Service is binded, it'll return -1.

Make sure the initialize() is called on the last line before the app/game starts

```
I/DSPluginJNI( 3346): [callMethodWithBoolReturn] java_rtn = 00000001  // initialize() is called
I/DSPluginJNI( 3346): [callMethodWithIntReturn] java_rtn = ffffffff
I/DsClientFactory( 3346): DsClient is: android.media.dolby.DolbySurroundClient
I/DsClient07Wrapper( 3346): onClientConnected v=DS version 0.7.0.0
I/DSJavaPlugin( 3346): Dolby client connected… // DsService is binded
```